# Can I set up alerts for when a CDN is down?

Tags: cdn, notification

My client use a CDN on their website. Sometimes the CDN is not properly working and images aren't loading.

Can I automatically get a notification whenever the CDN is not working properly? The client is using Pagely.

Comment: Why would you want your customer to continue to use a CDN that has problems? a good CDN will be hosted in multiple locations and will never be down, but to answer your question... [Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/) or setup a cron job to perform a wget on the CDN every 10secs or so.

Comment: You can use Javascript to create your own fallback method.

Comment: Perfectly agree with simon. CDN main aims is, they distribute your website content on other locations, so user get it fast from near location with low latency. CDN should be never down, if one pop location is down, then they can request from other pop location. I can clearly say that your CDN not distributing your content to other location, it is just like any normal server, but they give some caching functionality with easy setup so people love them, which actually anyone can do with server side functionality as well.

Answer (score 2):

How to get notifications on if a CDN is still online largely depends on the CDN and how they publish outage information. Some have a status site that you can see (but may or may not be able to subscribe to notifications on), others send out an email to account holders, and others still have no notifications at all. Regarding Pagely specifically since that is the CDN provider you have mentioned they appear to have a status site located at http://status.pagely.com/ however I have been unable to find any way within the status site to subscribe to notifications for outages.

As you mention there have been multiple times where the CDN has gone offline I would tend to recommend changing CDN providers as the point of a CDN isn't just to provide static content closer to the end user for site speed reasons but also to provide redundancy so that a server outage doesn't bring the whole site crashing down. Pagely advertises that they are providing WordPress hosting and so the CDN aspect is only one part of what they do and that they are hosting in the Amazon Web Services Cloud. If issues continue to be experienced you may be in a position to get better service by hosting the site directly through AWS instead of going through Pagely but that would be something that you would have to decide upon based on if the impact from the outages outweighs the benefits of having a managed WordPress hosting service.

Answer (score 2):

Get another server and install something like Zabbix, PRTG or IPHost and make a sensor to check a http get with response validation. Have it poll the image and report back to you with success, performance warning or down.